# How to overlap children while keeping parents as is in flex direction column

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two parent `flex items` positioned as `flex-direction: column`.

The first parent has two children. One child is optional, and sometimes it is removed.

I want the optional child to be on top of the other child. When I add/remove the optional content, I want the layout to not be affected.

I tried setting negative margin on the optional child (see commented css), then the outer parent below overlaps the first parent with children.

Why does that happen, and how can I overlap two children while keeping outer parents as is?

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      content
    </div>
    <div class='child optional'>
      more content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    content
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.parent {
  width: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {  
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.optional {
  /* margin-top: -60px; */
}
```

http://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/JdzWqK

Answer (score 0):

My 1st advice to you is not to use a class name with a space in it like `"optional child"`. Choose a name like `"optional-child"`.

My 2nd advice is not using negative margins almost never. I can't even imagine a situation in which it could be a good solution.
The solution to the problem may be: Setting the div tag with class name `"optional-child"` before the div tag with class name `"child"`. And If you want to remove it with a js code for use the command
`document.getElementByClassName("optional-child")='0px'`